# How to optimize this Controller and Thymeleaf-View?

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, thymeleaf, form-submit

Hi, I need to migrate a former Typo3/PHP application to a Spring Boot Web app. Therefore I extracted the domain model from the underlying MySQL database, which worked relatively well. Currently the application works, but I am quite unsatisfied.
This is my first Spring Boot application and I'm a little unhappy with my current controller and view because I think it should be cleaner and better structured. 
For instance I had to take the keys of the ModelAttributes from the database schema and the swapping into separate ModelAttributes seems a bit clumsy. Also, the data is currently only displayed on one page and I want to move search results after form processing to a result page. I've looked at examples and tried to implement them, but I failed to send all data to a result page using a post method. I would be very happy about a code review so that I know about whether I am on the right track and can continue in this way.

Many Thanks

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class WorkController {

private WorkServiceImpl workService;
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WorkController.class);

public WorkController(WorkServiceImpl workService) {
    this.workService = workService;
}

@Data
public class WerksucheForm {
    private String selectedSearchTerm;
    private Integer selectedWorkTypeValue;
    private Integer selectedOriginalLanguageValue;
    private Integer selectedAuthenticityValue;
    private Integer selectedStartDate;
    private Integer selectedEndDate;

    public WerksucheForm() {

    }
}

@GetMapping(value = "/werksuche", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
public ModelAndView getWorksBySearchTerm(@ModelAttribute WerksucheForm extract, ModelAndView mv) {
    try {
        Integer startDate = extract.selectedStartDate;
        Integer endDate = extract.selectedEndDate;
        String searchTerm = extract.selectedSearchTerm;
        Integer type = extract.selectedWorkTypeValue;
        Integer language = extract.selectedOriginalLanguageValue;
        Integer authenticity = extract.selectedAuthenticityValue;
        mv.setViewName("werksuche");
        mv.getModel().put("searchResult", workService.findBySearchTerm(searchTerm));
        logger.info("Initial status of values:" + searchTerm + " " + type + " " + language + " " + authenticity + " " + startDate + " " + endDate);

        if (type != null || language != null || authenticity != null || startDate != null || endDate != null) {
            mv.getModel().put("searchResult", workService.findByFilter(searchTerm, type, language, authenticity, startDate, endDate));
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        logger.error("SearchTerm is null: " + e);
    }
    mv.getModel().put("filter", new WerksucheForm());

    return mv;
}

@ModelAttribute("singleSelectAllWorkTypeValues")
public Map<Integer, String> getSingleSelectWorkTypeAllValues() {
    return new HashMap<Integer, String>() {
        {
            put(40, "Oper");
            put(10, "Ballett");
            put(60, "Sinfonie");
            put(30, "Triosonate");
            put(80, "Lied");
            put(70, "Arie");
        }
    };
}

@ModelAttribute("singleSelectAllOriginalLanguage")
public Map<Integer, String> getSingleSelectAllOriginalLanguageValues() {
    return new HashMap<Integer, String>() {
        {
            put(1, "Italienisch");
            put(2, "Französisch");
            put(3, "Deutsch");
        }
    };
}

@ModelAttribute("singleSelectAllAuthenticity")
public Map<Integer, String> getSingleSelectAllAuthenticityValues() {
    return new HashMap<Integer, String>() {
        {
            put(0, "Authentisch");
            put(3, "Zugeschrieben");
            put(4, "Zugeschrieben (Musik verschollen");
            put(2, "Zweifelhaft");
            put(1, "Fälschlich zugeordnet");
        }
    };
}
}
```

Associated View:

```
<body>
<h1 id="title">Werkverzeichnis</h1>

<div th:replace="fragments/navbar :: navbar">
</div>
<div th:replace="fragments/fixedSidebar:: fixedSidebar">
</div>

<form action="#" th:action="@{/werksuche}" th:object="${searchResult}" method="get">
    <div th:object="${filter}">
        <div class="form-group searchTerm">
            <h2>Werksuche</h2>
            <label for="search">Suchbegriffe</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" th:field="*{selectedSearchTerm}" />
        </div>
        <br/>
        <h4>Werkfilter</h4>
        <div class="form-group filterByWorkType">
            <label for="filterByWorktype">Werktyp</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="filter" id="filterByWorktype" th:field="*{selectedWorkTypeValue}">

                <option selected th:value="null"></option>
                <option th:each="dropdownValue: ${singleSelectAllWorkTypeValues}" th:value="${dropdownValue.getKey()}" th:text="${dropdownValue.getValue()}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="form-group filterByLanguage">
            <label for="filterByOriginalLanguage">Originalsprache</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="filter" id="filterByOriginalLanguage" th:field="*{selectedOriginalLanguageValue}">

                <option selected th:value="null"></option>
                <option th:each="dropdownvalue : ${singleSelectAllOriginalLanguage}" th:value="${dropdownvalue.getKey()}" th:text="${dropdownvalue.getValue()}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="form-group filterByAuthenticity">
            <label for="filterByAuthenticity">Authentizität</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="filter" id="filterByAuthenticity" th:field="*{selectedAuthenticityValue}">

                <option selected th:value="null"></option>
                <option th:each="dropdownvalue : ${singleSelectAllAuthenticity}" th:value="${dropdownvalue.getKey()}" th:text="${dropdownvalue.getValue()}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="form-group dateRange">
            <label for="fromToRange">Zeitliche Eingrenzung</label>
            <div id="fromToRange">
                <label for="startDate">von</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate" th:field="*{selectedStartDate}">
                <label for="endDate">bis</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate" th:field="*{selectedEndDate}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="suchen" />
    </div>
    <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(searchResult)}">
        <br/>
        <table id="resultTable">
            <tbody>
                <th:block th:each="result,iter : ${searchResult}">
                    <tr>
                        <td th:text="${iter.index+1}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${result.getTitle()}"></td>
                        <td th:utext="${result.getGenesis()}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </th:block>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

The whole business logic lies in Services and is mostly made of spring-data Specifications and Search Criterias. The database contains a composer's catalogue of works and should be queried via filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it again and got it. Now the query results are displayed on a result page after form processing.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/werksuche")
public String workSearchForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("filter", new WerksucheForm());
    return "werksuche";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/werksuche")
public String submitForm(@Valid WerksucheForm extract, BindingResult bindingResult, 
Model model) {
    Integer startDate = extract.selectedStartDate;
    Integer endDate = extract.selectedEndDate;
    String searchTerm = extract.selectedSearchTerm;
    Integer type = extract.selectedWorkTypeValue;
    Integer language = extract.selectedOriginalLanguageValue;
    Integer authenticity = extract.selectedAuthenticityValue;
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "werksuche";
    }
    model.addAttribute("searchResult",workService.findBySearchTerm(searchTerm));
    if (type != null || language != null || authenticity != null || startDate != null || endDate != null) {
        model.addAttribute("searchResult", workService.findByFilter(searchTerm, type, language, authenticity, startDate, endDate));
    }
    model.addAttribute("filter", new WerksucheForm());
    return "result";
}
```

POST redirects the data to the result page.

Is there something else I could do in order to reduce complexity?